# Thermal resistance unit

Tags: heatsink, thermal

Referring to the Infineon ICE2A365 datasheet.

In the datasheet, the thermal resistance from junction to ambient is 90 K/W.

What is K? Is it kelvin or degrees C.

If it is kelvin than changing it to degrees centigrade will be approx -183C/W, which does not make any sense.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The only difference between them is the zero value (position of origin).
Notice that the difference between any two points is the same on both the scales.
So 1°C rise in temperature means 1K rise in temperature.

1 degree C is equivalent to 1 degree K.

See image:

[image]

The SI units of thermal resistance are kelvins per watt or the equivalent degrees Celsius per watt (the two are the same since the intervals are equal: Δ1 K = Δ1 °C).

Answer (score 1):

As both answers above are true, they are missing the zero (0) reference points:
- For °C (Celsius or "Centigrade") scale the 0 reference point is the freezing temperature of water. The °C value can be either positive or negative as needed.
- For °K (Kelvin) scale the 0 reference point is the "absolute zero" temperature as follows: "By international agreement, absolute zero is defined as precisely 0 K on the Kelvin scale, which is a thermodynamic (absolute) temperature scale and –273.15 degrees Celsius on the Celsius scale." The °K value can only be positive.

For both °C and °K scales the difference between any two measured temperatures is exactly the same, for instance 1°C difference = 1°K difference.

Answer (score -2):

I was taught that 1 degree centigrade is an actual temperature and 1 centigrade degree is an increment of one degree.
This avoids confusion.
J Garrioch.